# Get specific element in Json string in php problem

Tags: php

This is my data struuture:

```
array(6) { 
  ["id"]=> string(15) "264729823543848" 
  ["application"]=> array(2) { 
    ["name"]=> string(7) "Prizzer" 
    ["id"]=> string(15) "100398126714422" 
  } 
  ["to"]=> array(2) { 
    ["name"]=> string(18) "Danielle McPherson" 
    ["id"]=> string(15) "100000204975672" 
  } 
  ["from"]=> array(2) { 
    ["name"]=> string(13) "Billy Zearott" 
    ["id"]=> string(10) "1292797153" 
  }
  ["message"]=> string(45) "Become my Prizzer Buddie and win Real Prizes!" 
  ["created_time"]=> string(24) "2011-08-02T06:06:39+0000" 
}
```

I get this by dumping the var:

```
$obj = json_decode($returned_content, true);
var_dump($obj);
```

Now I need to extract only the value `"100000204975672"` which is the third id right after `"Danielle McPherson"`. How do I do that?

Comment: After cleaning up your output (use code tags!), your question became a lot more clear.

Comment: @K4emic: How is your edit substantially better than mine? ;) (this is *not* a JSON string, for example)

Comment: itslikewhenyoudontevencareaboutwhitespaceanymore.

Comment: @K4emic: Have a look at the [edit history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/6926367/revisions). ;-)

Comment: Your edit is superior to mine, but the editor presented me with the original text, not your edit. Shouldn't the editor notify me that new edits were made? Apologies for the previous, slightly rude, comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to look at your example a couple of times because of the nesting. Thanks for the edit @K4emic - much easier to read now.

```
echo $obj['to']['id'];
```